# Django : Insert data o model using excel file

Tags: django, database, file, import

I'm working with `Django` and `postgres`, and I have a model called `fournisseurs` , what I want to do is let the user import a csv/excel file that contains colums similar to those of my Model :

```
class fournisseur:
   id_facture=models.IntegerField()
   numpiece=models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

the excel file contains also colums `id_facture` , `numpiece` ; can I let my user import this file and when submiting , Django inserts automatically on my database that file data ? 
if so please let me know where can I start to achieve what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
if request.method =='POST':
    form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        # file is saved
        form.save()
        csvfile = request.FILES['f']

        try: csvfile.open()
        except:
             msg = "Cannot open file - is it CSV?"
             return render ...

        my_data = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in my_data:
            f = fourmisseur (
                id_facture = row[0],                
                numpiece   = row[1])
            f.save()
```

You would need to include appropriate validation

Comment: Thank You for your answer I'll try to do as you told me.